# Using Objects#hash(Object...) for hashCode method?

Tags: java, java-7

What do you think about using `Objects#hash(Object...)` in a `hashCode()` method?

```
int a = 1; 
boolean b = true; 
Date c = new Date(); 
String d = "1234";
Object e = new ch.example.blabla.Foo();

// Java 7
public int hashCode() {
  return Objects.hash(a, b, c, d, e);
}

// or using Java 6 
public int hashCode() {
  return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] {a, b, c, d, e});
}
```

Of course under normal circumstances such as having an `equals(Object)` method too and so on. Joshua Bloch writes in his book how to write a good `hashCode()` method using his rules/recipe such as shifting bits and so on.

Above example does not follow these rules for primitive datatypes... so my question is, is it ok to handle primitive datatypes like objects (autoboxing) instead of following Bloch's recipe or using Apache Commons `HashCodeBuilder`?

`Objects#hash(Object...)` was introduced in Java 7 and invokes only `Arrays.hashCode(Object[])`, so this question is also focused to Java 6 users.

Thank you for your responses/ideas/suggestions!

---

**I really don't understand when older questions are getting closed as a duplicate because of newer ones.**

However, there is a question **with better answers** here:

- [Use Objects.hash() or own hashCode() implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45832458/use-objects-hash-or-own-hashcode-implementation)

Comment: I think this does follow the rules for primitive types (autoboxed wrappers hash the same way), but the downside of this could be performance due to all the garbage produced.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if a modern jvm was able to optimize all the boxing and array creation away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Objects.hash() or own hashCode() implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45832458/use-objects-hash-or-own-hashcode-implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapper classes like `Integer`, `Double` and `Boolean` do indeed implement the rules which are described in Effective Java of Joshua Bloch. Thank you to Marko Topolnik for highlighting that out.

He's also mentioning a downside which could lead into performance issues. However, Jörn Horstmann assumes that this might be optimized by mordern JVMs.

We're going with this approach (`Objects.hash(a, b, c)`) since it's way more readable than writing our own `hashCode()` method. And if really necessary (if we run into performance issues) we do implement primitive hash code by ourselves.

Marko, Jörn, thank you for your comments. If you're going to write an answer, I'll change the accepted answer to the best answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that Objects.hash does not work well if you want the hash code for an array, since `Objects.hash` internally calls `Arrays.hashCode`. Proper array hash code generation requires `Arrays.deepHashCode`.