# Use Objects.hash() or own hashCode() implementation?

Tags: java, hash

I have recently discovered the [`Objects.hash()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...)) method.

My first thought was, that this tidies up your `hashCode()` implementation a lot. See the following example:

```
@Override
//traditional
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 67 * hash + (int)(this.id ^ (this.id >>> 32));
    hash = 67 * hash + (int)(this.timestamp ^ (this.timestamp >>> 32));
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.severity);
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.thread);
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.classPath);
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.message);
    return hash;
}

@Override
//lazy
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, timestamp, severity, thread, classPath, message);
}
```

Although I have to say that this seems too good to be true. Also I've never seen this usage.

Are there any downsides of using `Objects.hash()` compared to implementing your own hash code? When would I choose each of those approaches?

**Update**

Although this topic is marked as resolved, feel free to keep posting answers that provide new information and concerns.

Comment: Also see `HashCodeBulider`: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html

Comment: But the commons builder uses reflection. It is convenient but an absolute performance killer.

Comment: @NPE I really want to keep it with the natives. I'm not a big fan of the whole  external apache common stuff

Comment: Use Lombok and `@EqualsAndHashCode`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks but I d'like to keep my dependencies clean.

Comment: As of JDK 16, just use a `record`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Note that the parameter of `Objects.hash` is `Object...`. This has two main consequences:

- Primitive values used in the hash code calculation have to be boxed, e.g. `this.id` is converted from `long` to `Long`.
- An `Object[]` has to be created to invoke the method.

The cost of creating of these "unnecessary" objects may add up if `hashCode` is called frequently.

Comment: As with all performance concerns, you should prove to yourself that you care before you care.

Comment: @CandiedOrange yes; on the other hand, don't write code you *might* have to care about. I mean, you could implement `hashCode` with `return 0;` if you're not going to care about performance until you have proven otherwise. Since you only have to write it once, and likely your IDE is going to generate the code for you, you may as well opt for the verbose-but-performant version. But I wouldn't rush to change either form to the other in existing code.

Answer (score 30):

Following is implementation of **Objects.hash** - which is calling Arrays.hashCode internally.

```
public static int hash(Object... values) {
    return Arrays.hashCode(values);
}
```

This is implementation of **Arrays.hashCode** method

```
public static int hashCode(Object a[]) {
    if (a == null)
        return 0;

    int result = 1;

    for (Object element : a)
        result = 31 * result + (element == null ? 0 : element.hashCode());

    return result;
}
```

So I agree with @Andy
The cost of creating of these "unnecessary" objects may add up if hashCode is called frequently. If you are implementing yourself it would be faster.

Answer (score 14):

I would like to try and make a strong argument for both.

#### Opening disclaimer

For this answer, `Objects.hash()`, `Objects.hashCode()`, and any function provided by any library that performs this role are interchangeable. First, I would like to argue, use `Objects.hash()` or don't use the static Objects functions at all. Any argument for or against this method requires making assumptions about the compiled code that are not guaranteed to be true. (For example, the compiler optimizer may convert the function call into an inline call, thus bypassing the extra call stack and object allocation. Just like how loops that do nothing useful don't make it to the compiled version (unless you turn off the optimizer). You also have no guarantee that future Java versions won't include the JVM version like C# does in it's version of this method. (for security reasons I believe)) So the only safe argument you can make regarding using this function, is that it is generally safer to leave the details of a proper hash to this function than to try to implement your own naive version.

#### For Objects.hash

- Guaranteed to be a good hash.
- Takes 5 seconds to implement.
- Yours would have had a bug in it (somehow especially if you copy-pasted the implementation)

#### Against Objects.hash

- The Java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode-java.lang.Object-) make no promises about hash cross-compatibility (Will a JVM v6 and JVM v8 give the same values? always? across OS?)
- The thing about [hashCodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()), They work best if "evenly distributed". So if an int value is only valid for range 1 to 100, you might want to "redistribute" its hash-codes to not all be part of the same bucket.
- If you have any requirement that makes you question how Objects.hash works, reliability/performance wise, Think carefully if the hash-code is really what you want, and implement a custom hash-coding method that addresses **your** needs.

Comment: You are referring to `Objects.hashCode` here: do you mean to do so, or do you mean `Objects.hash` (which is what OP is asking about)?

Comment: @AndyTurner As far as I'm really concerned in this answer, any library provided hashing function is interchangeable and doesn't really affect the point. If you really care about the difference between how hash and hashCode work, you probably shouldn't be using either of them.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question, which is asking about the advantages/disadvantages of *`Objects.hash`* to calculate a hash code from multiple fields, vs doing it "by hand". `Objects.hashCode` simply invokes `Object.hashCode()` on its parameter, handling the case of null. If you use this, you've still got to combine the hash codes somehow. The two are not interchangable.

Comment: @AndyTurner They are not interchangeable in the sense one is "hash this" and the other is "hash these". I view them as interchangeable in the sense that you are asking an API to handle the hashing logic for you. In my answer, I try to say "If you aren't using `Objects.hash`, you probably shouldn't be using `Objects.hashCode` either. It really does only boil down to "Why is this available function insufficient, and what do I need to do to make a sufficient version?"

Answer (score 9):

Joshua Bloch in his book Effective Java, 3rd edition, p. 53 discourages usage of `Objects.hash(...)` if performance is critical.

Primitives are being autoboxed and there is a penalty of creating an `Object` array.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd side with the short code first, because it is so much quicker to read, change and verify as correct, which all serve to avoid bugs when modifying the class.

Then for performance-critical classes, or where fields are costly to hash, another available "tool" is to cache the result (like `String` does):

```
// volatile not required for 32-bit sized primitives
private int hash;

@Override
public final int hashCode() {
    // "Racy Single-check idiom" (Item 71, Effective Java 2nd ed.)
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0) {
        h = Objects.hash(id, timestamp, severity, thread, classPath, message);
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

In this lockless-threadsafe pattern (which assumes an immutable class, naturally) there's a slim chance that `hash` might get initialised by different threads multiple times, but this does not matter because the result of the public method is always identical. The key to (memory-visibility) correctness is ensuring that `hash` is never written and read more than once in the method.

The array-construction penalty of `Objects.hash` might be lower than you imagine once the code gets JIT-inlined & optimised by the C2 compiler.

(UPDATED) The good folks over at JDK had something baking that was pitched at eliminating the overheads of `Objects::hash` mentioned in other answers, but apparently the difference was not enough to matter, to that particular method: [JEP 348: Java Compiler Intrinsics for JDK APIs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/348)

Comment: Nice implementation to avoid additional calculations but what if Object is mutable and one of the parameters used for hash calculations changes?

Comment: Sure, then don't cache it, but then: also think twice before using any mutable object as a key in a hash-based map/set. Doing so can break the whole collection - objects might go "missing" inside it, etc.

Comment: If `h` is 0, you'll end up not caching it. `String` uses an additional `hashIsZero` field to deal with that case (which makes the JMM issues even more subtle).

Comment: Indeed, it is important to ensure `h` is not 0 for common cases. Simply adding a constant is usually sufficient. The hash fn *should* then ensure the frequency of 0 occuring in non-corner cases is exceedingly low and thus averages out to ~ nothing. I think it'd be rare to ever need this [significant extra complexity](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2019-April/059480.html) in most real-world cases. `String` does need to cater for very broad scenarios - but even there it got away without this mini-optimisation just fine up until 2019, despite its ubiquity.